# UIActionSheet and UIView

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiactionsheet

I want to create a UIActionSheet but I've also a UIView and this last one must be selectable.
How you can see I can't use the date picker. Ideas?

[image: Action Sheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. A UIActionSheet is modal by definition.